# Check for a string in a debug message in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `View` with a `view.backgroundColor`. When I print the value to the debug-log i get

`<UIImage:0x283b31b00 named(main: bg_200_200) {200, 200} renderingMode=automatic>`

Is it possible to check this "String" (I know it's not a real string) for an occurence of a text, e.g. if it contains "bg_200"?
Thanks!

Comment: you mean like `view.backgroundColor.description.contains("bg_200")`? It's okey for debugging purposes. Not okey for production code.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, like that, but for production code :)

Comment: Then it's not okey and even checking the value of `view.backgroundColor` would be strange. You are setting the value therefore you should now what's inside. The values are generated from some `@State`. Check the state instead.

Comment: Well that's right @Sulthan I will try it like this. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI is always generated from some data model. Instead of checking the values inside UI, it's better to test the values in data model that were used to generate the UI.

This is especially obvious in SwiftUI which is always data driven and is always generated again when data model changes.

In UIKit this might be less obvious - for example, when you are changing background from an action, e.g.:

```
@IBAction func onButtonClicked() {
   myView.backgroundColor = ...
}
```

If you need to access that value later, it's always better to store it inside  data model and then use that value to change the UI, e.g.:

```
private var buttonWasClicked = false

@IBAction func onButotnClicked() {
   buttonWasClicked = true
   updateBackground()
}

private func updateBackground() {
   myView.backgroundColor = buttonWasClicked ? UIColor.red : UIColor.clear
}
```